# How to differentiate between class get set and constructor attributes

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

What is the hidden field(argument1), I'm getting in chrome console?

```
class ClassName {
  constructor(argument1) {
    this._argument1 = argument1;
  }

  get argument1() {
    return this._argument1 + " by get method.";
  }

  set argument1(value) {
    if (value.length < 4) {
      console.log("Please provide name with more length.");
      return;
    }
    this._argument1 = value;
  }
}

let object1 = new ClassName("abcde");
console.info(object1);
```

[chrome-console-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAPoD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your getter - **get argument1()**
see the tooltip before you expand the field:
[image: Invoke property "getter"]